# Wordpress Single sign-on using negotiate-auth.trusted-uris doesn't work in wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, firefox, single-sign-on, kerberos

I use the code below to log users on an intranet using kerberos.
Problem is that it works fine if user use the kerberos dialog box (see the screenshot), but if user had configured his browser to use `negotiate-auth.trusted-uris` he can't access to wp-admin and is always blocked by wp-login page.
Why? And how can I resolve this problem?
Thanks

```
add_action('init', 'kerberosauth');
add_action('admin_init', 'kerberosauth',1);
add_filter("authenticate", "kerberosauth", 10, 3);
function kerberosauth()
{
if(isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])):
$remote_user = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];

if(!is_user_logged_in()):
if(get_user_by('email', $remote_user)):

$user = get_user_by('email', $remote_user);
$ID = $user->ID;
$pass = $user->user_pass;
$login = $user->user_login;

kb_log_user($ID,$login);
else: //Créer l'utilisateur
kb_create_user($remote_user);
endif;
// else:
endif;

endif;
}

function kb_log_user($ID,$login)
{
      wp_set_current_user( $ID );
      do_action('set_current_user');
      wp_set_auth_cookie( $ID,$remember = true );
      //do_action( 'wp_login', $login );  
      wp_get_current_user();
                   //echo "You are logged in ".$login;
}

function kb_create_user($user)
{
    $username = preg_replace("/\@(domain)\.(tld)/", "", $user);
    $pwd = isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])?$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']:wp_generate_password(12);
    wp_create_user($username,$pwd,$user );
    //lancer l'authentification
    kerberosauth();
    print_r("User created ".$username);
}
```

Comment: Resolved : The problem was neither kerberos nor `negotiate-auth.trusted-uris`
I just needed to enable sunrise on wp-config.php : `define( 'SUNRISE', 'on' );`